# Como excluir uma linha específica de uma base no R

Tags: r

Estou fazendo validação de uma base no R é identifiquei umas linhas que não fazem sentido então será necessário excluir algumas delas. Qual a melhor maneira de excluir as linhas que contem 'N', 'P' e 'K' da variável base$fraude no exemplo abaixo?
 Tentei essa função e não deu certo: subset(base_renomeada, fraude = "K")

[image: Excluir as Linhas N, P, S]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com `tidyverse` você pode fazer assim:

```
df <- data.frame(
  fraude = c('K', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'S'), 
  valores = c(1, 2, 18405914, 1, 111044)
)

  fraude  valores
1      K        1
2      M        2
3      N 18405914
4      P        1
5      S   111044

library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  filter(! fraude %in% c('N', 'P', 'K'))

  fraude valores
1      M       2
2      S  111044
```

Answer (score 2):

```
base_renomeada <- base_renomeada[!base_renomeada %in% c("N", "P", "K"), ]
```

Ou se você quiser informar aqueles que você quer manter:

```
base_renomeada <- base_renomeada[base_renomeada %in% c("S", "M"), ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Com `subset` tal como na pergunta será

```
subset(base, !fraude %in% c("N", "P", "K"))
```

É mais eficaz em termos de desempenho usar um índice lógico.

```
i <- !base$fraude %in% c("N", "P", "K")
result <- base[i, ]
```